# How to defend routes in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I came across a problem which I dont know how to fix. I dont even know where to start.
The problem is next : I have url "localhost:4000/"  If I will type url "localhost:4000/homepage" It will redirect me to my home page,But i want to restrict this access if token is not preserved.

Here are my routes :

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LogIn from "./components/LogIn/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register/Register";
import Homepage from './components/HomePage/HomePage'
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile'
import Posts from './components/addPostUI/Posts'
import "./app.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path={"/"} exact component={LogIn} />
          <Route path={"/login"} component={LogIn} />
          <Route path={"/registration"} component={Register} />
          <Route path={'/homepage'} component={Homepage} />
          <Route path={'/profile'} component={Profile} />
          <Route path={"/posts"} component={Posts} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any suggestions on how to restrict access and defend my routes?

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to restrict your Routes conditionally. The basic approach you can follow here is:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route 
           path='/homepage' 
           render = {() => {
              if(accessToken || localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
                 return <Homepage />;
              } else {
                 return <Redirect to='/login' />; 
              }
            }}
          />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

You can follow along with these steps whenever there is a need for conditional routing.

Answer (score 0):

First determine what you want to authenticate users by, then you can do the following inside the page you want to protect, before the page renders.

```
if (failed access condition) return <Redirect to='/some route you want to redirect to' />
```

Be sure to import Redirect like this:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
```

**Also Consider**

If you have a database, be sure to restrict access to the data based on the access token as well and don't depend on client side code to protect data.